# How to give img src path from outside of angular project while i am development stage

Tags: angular7

I am trying give img src path from outside of angular project .please resolve my problem as soon as possible.
   My folder structure were look like

```
       ProjectName
             \backend
                \assets
                  \images\test.png
             angularprojectroot
                  \app
                     \src
                        \component files
```

Comment: Where is your html file. Where you are trying to put image?

Comment: inside the component.html file.

Answer (score 1):

In file paths you can go up a step with `..`

```
<img src="../../../../backend/assets/images/test.png" />
```

Definitely for development only. In production serve the test.png from your server.

In your specific case using angular.json add this to your assets:

```
// assets is an array. Keep the other items in the array but add the one displayed below
"assets": ["../../../backend/assets/images/test.png"]
```

Then I believe you can just refer to the image as test.png:

```
<img src="test.png" />
```

Comment: Fiddle with the number of `../` repeats. VS code will probably help you with that if you're using it.

Comment: In the browser when you are in development what is the URL? Is it localhost?

Comment: localhost:4200/

Comment: Your project is being served from a server inside the angular project folder, so you can't access the file outside the project. Try going into your file directory in the folder angular made called (build | dist | public) and opening the file index.html in your browser instead. Then you can use `..`.

Comment: build Time it working fine .i am using in angular.json like this
"assets":[
     "glob";"**/*",
    "input":"Outisde project folder",